# Get data from ajax and pass it to a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div popup and there are some links that show this popup. 
the problem is here that the content of popup will be different depending on what user click on links:

```
//my div popup
<div id="show-popup">
    <p>$value</p>
</div>

//one,two and three values fetch from database by using Ajax.
<a href="#show-popup" onclick="toGetValues(1)">show popup = the value must be one</a>
<a href="#show-popup" onclick="toGetValues(2)">show popup = the value must be two</a>
<a href="#show-popup" onclick="toGetValues(3)">show popup = the value must be three</a>
```

now, I don't know how to send 1,2,3 to database by Ajax then how to open that popup after fetch value from database .

I know by below method I can send some value to my url but how I can open popup and then load new value on this popup ?

```
$.post('myurl' , {id:id} , function(data){
    //do stuf
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html()` ; chain `.show()` to `.html()` if element is not displayed before `click`.

To append `data` instead of replacing existing `data` at `#show-popup` , substitute `.append()` for `.html()`

```
function toGetValues(id) {
  $.post("myurl", {id:id}, function(data) {
      // do stuff
      // `.html()` replaces `html` of `#show-popup`
      $("#show-popup").append("<p>$" + data + "</p>")
      // .show()
   })
}
```

Comment: when I use `.html("...")`, my content of my popup will be override. how to pass data  without override?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian If you want to append values to `#show-popup` instead of replace values substitute  `.append()` for `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
function toGetValues(myvar)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {mypar: myvar},
        success: function (response) {
           $( "#show-popup").html(response);
           $( "#show-popup").dialog();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get( "url", {id: id} ).done(
  function( data ) {
    $("#show-popup").append("<p>" + data + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your code, what it does and how it should solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the id from the onclick event you have just to send it and put the the `value` you get back as responce from your PHP page to the paragraph `p` using  `text()` :

```
function toGetValues(id) 
{
  $.post("myurl", {id:id}, function(value) {
      $("#show-popup p").text(value); //append returned value from php to the  paragraph
      $("#show-popup").dialog(); //Show popup
   })
}
```